# Как правильно вывести строки внутри скобки (из подмассива)

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть такой код:

```
var textt = "Текст 1, текст 2, текст 3, текст 4 текст 5";

var wordArr = [["а", "б", "в"], ["г", "д", "е"], ["ж", "з", "и"], ["к", "л", "м"]];

var res = textt.match(/текст/gi); /*ищем совпадние*/

var lenres = res.length; /*количество совпадений*/

/*Проходим по циклу*/
for(var i = 0; lenres>i; i++){


if(res != undefined){

//Составляем регулярное выражение
textt = textt.replace(new RegExp(textt, 'giu'),function(full_text){

var ArrPrep = "";

/*с помощью второго циклу добавляем запятые для строк внутри скобки*/
for(var k = 0; wordArr.length > k; k++){if(wordArr.length-2 >= k){var wordBaseZap = ", "}else{var wordBaseZap = ""} ArrPrep+= wordArr[k]+wordBaseZap;}

//Выводим ответ
return full_text +"("+ ArrPrep +")";

});
}

}

textt; /*Результат*/
```

Получается такой ответ:

```
Текст 1, текст 2, текст 3, текст 4, текст 5(а,б,в, г,д,е, ж,з,и, к,л,м)
```

Как переделать код так, чтобы получился такой ответ:

```
Текст 1(а,б,в), текст 2(г,д,е), текст 3(ж,з,и), текст 4(к,л,м), текст 5(а,б,в)
```

Comment: заумное решение какое-то у вас. Нормально опишите критерий разделения искомой строки и замены. что вы там ищите, вхождения `текст\s+\d+` ? или это пример оторванный от действительности?

Answer (score 2):

Вы написали немного неправильную логику. Суть в том, что не надо хранить найденные кусочки текста, чтоб затем с помощью дополнительного регулярно выражения искать их снова и заменять. Во-первыйх, поиск уже выполнен, и повторно смысла сделать нет. Во-вторых, может оказаться что новый поиск найдет другое совпадение и подставит новый текст туда. Я предлагаю сделать замены сразу

```
var textt = "Текст 1, текст 2, текст 3, текст 4 текст 5";
var wordArr = [["а", "б", "в"], ["г", "д", "е"], ["ж", "з", "и"], ["к", "л", "м"]];
textt = textt.replace(/(текст\s+)(\d+)/ig, function(match, p1,p2) {
    return  p1 + p2 + '(' + wordArr[(p2 - 1) % wordArr.length ].join(', ')  +')';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо будет определиться, что делать если кол-во элементов(в `texts` и `wordArr`) не совпадают.

```js
const regex = /Текст [0-9]/gi;

const texts = "Текст 1, текст 2, текст 3, текст 4 текст 5".match(regex);

const wordArr = [["а", "б", "в"], ["г", "д", "е"], ["ж", "з", "и"], ["к", "л", "м"]];

const result = [];


for (let i = 0; i < texts.length; i++) {
  console.log(`${texts[i]} (${wordArr[i]})`);
  
  result.push(`${texts[i]} (${wordArr[i]})`);
}

console.log(result.join(', '));
```